LaTeX Error: Counter too large
I'm getting a LaTeX Error: "Counter too large" when trying to write a list that surpass the letter z. I'm using the package enumitem and alphalph. I've tried a various number of alternatives and it only works with package enumerate that creates a great number of errors in my document.
Here's my code:
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\AlphAlph{\value{enumi}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no 
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no 
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no 
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no 
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
    \item In the "Supervisor information" section, the 
    \item The system does not allow creating a company if no
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

This is the final result: 
Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

More specifically, if you think this question is not similar, you're going to need to specify what should happen after (z).

Assuming that you want the list  "x), y), z)" to be followed by "aa), ab), ac)", etc., I have gotten it to work with the item letter being followed by a period; i.e., "aa. ab." and so on. However, there seems to be a conflict between the enumitem package and the alphalph package. One tip off for me was that even thought you \renewcommand with the \AlphAlph macro, you're getting lower case letters. I'll keep hacking at the problem.

Found the solution.
